# How to confirm if non-free firmware is needed for Intel Ethernet I219-V?

Tags: linux, drivers, ethernet

I have a NUC with an Intel I219-V NIC. It is running a live server so I cannot experiment, but I'd like to **verify** if the latest Debian Bullseye can run on it without non-free firmware for when I do a reinstall.

The device:

```
$ lspci | grep I219-V
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V (rev 21)
```

The driver:

```
$ find /sys | grep drivers.*00:1f.6
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/e1000e/0000:00:1f.6
```

The driver info:

```
$ sudo modinfo e1000e | grep ver
filename:       /lib/modules/5.10.0-0.bpo.9-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
description:    Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
vermagic:       5.10.0-0.bpo.9-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Where do I go from here to determine if I need non-free firmware for this device?

---

Following advice in comments, here is the output for `sudo dmesg | grep firmware`:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep firmware
[    0.095703] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    3.905222] platform regulatory.0: firmware: failed to load regulatory.db (-2)
[    3.905279] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
[    3.905339] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    3.940963] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
[    3.941628] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.9f0a2d68.0 8265-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.941652] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    4.266926] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin
[    4.267276] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    4.579111] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    4.580014] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
[    4.580017] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
[    6.491998] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    6.510143] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-12-16.ddc
```

The NIC is not mentioned here. Also, `sudo dmesg | grep e1000e`:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep e1000e
[    1.573441] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    1.573442] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.573686] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.779875] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    1.851416] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 94:c6:91:18:06:06
[    1.851419] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.851508] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 12, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    1.853178] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: renamed from eth0
[    7.172001] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
```

I am not using wifi and do not care about that NIC. Does this mean that I have no need for non-free firmware for the Ethernet NIC?

Comment: You could check the logs, there should be a line like this when the device driver was loaded: *[    time] module_name 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware dir/subdir/firmware.fw*, Then you can see if you need non-free to have that firmware file.

Comment: If you can change the kernel command line (for one boot): https://serverfault.com/questions/1026598/know-which-firmware-my-linux-kernel-has-loaded-since-booting